# Rails 3.1 - ActionView::Template::Error (No expansion found for :application): - No expansion found for :application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I get this weird error while running an App with Rails 3.1 in production.

In app/views/layouts/_javascripts.html.erb (file included in app/views/layouts/application.html.erb)

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

Is there any solution to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're not truly using Rails 3.1.

The expansion stuff was taken out of that in favour of using the Asset Pipeline. If you're still convinced that you really are using Rails 3.1, then perhaps try using a string:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

In *my* Rails 3.1 install, both strings and symbols work fine.

Comment: Thanks it works. But it's weird. I checked the Rails version and it gives me 3.1. Maybe it's because I use Mongoid (I dont include all dependencies in application.rb)

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently updated rails?  You might need to run `rake rails:update`